# Google big query backfill takes very long

Tags: google-bigquery

I am new to stack overflow. I use Google big query to connect data from multiple sources toegether. I have made a connection to Google ads (using data transfer from big query) and this works well. But when i run a  backfill of older data it takes more then 3 days to get the data from 180 days in big query. Google advises 180 days as maximum. But it takes so long. I want to do this for the past 2 years and multiple clients (we are an agency). I need to do this in chunks of 180 days.

Does anybody have a solution for this taking so long?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, BigQuery Data Transfer Service supports a maximum of 180 days (as you said) per backfill request and simultaneous backfill requests are not supported [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/working-with-transfers#backfilling).

BigQuery Data Transfer Service limits the maximum rate of incoming requests and enforces appropriate quotas on a per-project basis [[2]](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/quotas) and other BigQuery tasks in the project may be limiting the amount of resources used by the Transfer. Load jobs created by transfers are included in BigQuery's quotas on load jobs. It's important to consider how many transfers you enable in each project to prevent transfers and other load jobs from producing `quotaExceeded` errors.

If you need to increase the number of transfers, you can create other projects.
If you want to speed up the transfers for all your clients, you could split them into several projects, because it seems that’s an important amount of transfers that you are going to make there.